# compilation error while making a tetris game

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am making a tetris game following this http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/tetris/ tutorial in java. I keep getting this complilation error:

`File: /Users/Adelaide/Documents/MyGame/src/Shape.java  [line: (no source location)] File is in the wrong directory or is declared part of the wrong package. Directory name 'src' does not match package name 'zetcode'.`

I have tried moving it creating files called "zetcode" but I have no idea how to fix this, can you help me?

Comment: Provide stack traces, screenshots any additional information to help people

Comment: what is your `package` statement at the top of `Shape.java`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the package is package com.zetcode, I tried changing it but that seemed to create quite a few other errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java the `package` statement defines the namespace of your class. Here you are following a tutorial and it instructs you to use the `com.zetcode` package. That's fine, but the package also defines the directory structure that your files must live in. Here your Shape object must be in this folder structure:

`src/com/zetcode/Shape.java`

By leaving `Shape.java` in the root of your `src/` folder you are saying the class does not have a package (or rather it has the default unnamed package), so when the compiler sees the `package` statement in the source code it throws the error that you see.

#### Solution

The simplest solution is to move your source files into the folder structure that matches their package statements. Just imagine that the dots separating the words in the package name are slashes (path separators). Create the `src/com/zencode` directory and move the files into that folder. The compiler should be happier.

#### More Details About Packages

The package names are important because they allow Java to explicitly know which class is being used. You might have many `Shape` classes as long as they're in different packages, but when you `import` a specific class with its package the compiler knows for sure which to load.

Also you might notice that package names often start with the reverse of the web site domain of the company that makes it. For example, `com.abcxyz` will be the start of the package name for classes that the company with `www.abcxyz.com` as their website. It's a bad idea to use someone else's package name in your code because it's implying that the code you write is made by that company or organization.

You said that when you removed or changed the package statement you had other errors. That's probably because other classes (like Board.java) are importing the Shape class implicitly because they are in the same package and the compiler cannot find it if you change Shape's package name. You would need to change the package statements for all of the other classes to match the new package. Think of it like a family living at an address. If they moved, they all need to know their new address. Here the 'family' is the set of classes that belong together (Shape, Board, Tetris in your case) and the package name is their address.

Comment: When I did this and made it into src/com/zetcode in the project root in the project directory I got this: Error: None of the documents in [] is a valid source file! How would I solve this?

Comment: not without more details - where is there an array?

Comment: I believe I have fixed it, I re-saved some of the files to the src/com/zetcode file and that seemed to fix it